# How to programatically retrieve help strings for mode-line % constructs?

Tags: mode-line, help

I'm looking for a way to programmatically retrieve documentation for
mode-line-format %-constructs; this is part of a little project I'm
working on to help with mode-line customization.  So for example, if
the mode line contains "%e", I want something ike:

`(display-mode-line-format-percent-help "%e")`

to return:

`print error message about full memory.`

Right now the only way I can think of is to parse the help string for
mode-line-format, but that seems like it would put me in a state of
sin.  :-)  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to sin. The information you are after is only in `mode-line-format`, so that's what you have to inspect.